# How can I generate documentation related to my plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, documentation, yard

I am using Rails 3.1.0 and I have implemented a working plugin. As well as it should be done, its related files are located in the `ROOT_APP/vendor/plugins/my_plugin` directory.

Now, I am using the [YARD 0.7.4](http://rubydoc.info/docs/yard/file/docs/GettingStarted.md) gem and I would like to document that plugin. Anyway, when  I run the `yardoc` (or `yard doc`) command it seems do not consider my plugin so the related documentation is not generated (only that related to the "main" application is generated).

**How can I generate the documentation related to my plugin?**

Answer (score 0):

Your documentation should be generated if you run `yardoc` from inside your plugin directory.